# How to include R6 objects to share data across modules in golem Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, module, r6, golem

I’m trying to create a `Shiny` app using `golem` for the first time. `golem` structures `Shiny` apps with modules to help keep large `Shiny` apps modularized. However, modules don’t communicate with each other by default. I’d like to share data across modules. According to the `golem` documentation, [`R6` objects are a useful way to share data across modules](https://engineering-shiny.org/structuring-project.html#c.-the-strat%C3%A9gie-du-grand-r6).

However, in the [example provided in the `golem` documentation](https://engineering-shiny.org/common-app-caveats.html#a.-sharing-data-across-module), it is unclear where to put the `R6` generator. According to [Appsilon](https://appsilon.com/super-solutions-for-shiny-apps-using-r6-classes/), the `R6` generator goes in a separate `.R` file (e.g., `logger_manager.R`), and places a call in `global.R` to construct a new object from the class: `logger_manager = LoggerManager$new()`. However, there is no `global.R` file in a `golem`-based `Shiny` app.

Below is a minimal example of my `golem`-based `Shiny` app. I tried to follow the structure in the [example provided in the `golem` documentation](https://engineering-shiny.org/common-app-caveats.html#a.-sharing-data-across-module), but it does not seem to be sharing data across modules:

`app_ui.R`:

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    # Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    
    # List the first level UI elements here 
    fluidPage(
      mod_a_ui("a_ui_1"),
      mod_b_ui("b_ui_1")
    )
  )
}

golem_add_external_resources <- function(){
  
  add_resource_path(
    'www', app_sys('app/www')
  )
 
  tags$head(
    favicon(),
    bundle_resources(
      path = app_sys('app/www'),
      app_title = 'Test'
    ),
    # Add here other external resources
    # for example, you can add shinyalert::useShinyalert()
    shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  )
}
```

`app_server.R`:

```
app_server <- function( input, output, session ) {
  
  # Generate R6 Class
  QuestionnaireResponses <- R6Class(
    classname = "QuestionnaireResponses",
    public = list(
      resp_id = NULL,
      timezone = NULL,
      timestamp = NULL,
      gender = NULL,
    )
  )
  
  # Create new object to share data across modules using the R6 Class
  questionnaire_responses <- QuestionnaireResponses$new()
  
  # List the first level callModules here
  callModule(mod_a_server, "a_ui_1", questionnaire_responses)
  callModule(mod_b_server, "b_ui_1", questionnaire_responses)
}
```

`mod_a.R`:

```
mod_a_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    radioButtons(inputId = "gender",
                 label = "What is your sex?",
                 choices = c("Male" = 1,
                             "Female" = 2),
                 selected = character(0))
)
}

mod_a_server <- function(input, output, session, questionnaire_responses){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  # Add time start to the output vector
  timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
  timezone <- Sys.timezone()
  
  # Generate a survey-specific ID number
  resp_id <- paste0(sample(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), 10), collapse = "")
  
  # Assign values to R6 object
  questionnaire_responses$resp_id <- resp_id
  questionnaire_responses$timezone <- timezone
  questionnaire_responses$timestamp <- timestamp
  questionnaire_responses$gender <- input.gender
}
```

`mod_b.R`:

```
mod_b_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    print("questionnaire_responses$resp_id")
  )
}

mod_b_server <- function(input, output, session, questionnaire_responses){
  ns <- session$ns
  }
```

However, the data must not be being shared across modules because when I try to print `resp_id` in module B (which was generated in module A), I receive the following error:

```
An error has occurred!
object 'questionnaire_responses' not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue here is that you are trying to print the object **from the UI function** when your R6 object is passed **to the server function**.

In other words, you're trying to do a print in the `mod_b_ui` function, when the R6 object is passed to the `mod_b_server` function.

For your original question, you can create the R6 class inside a standard file, as  in https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/blob/master/golemR6/R/R6.R

Note though that your data object is **not reactive** and will not reprint when you change in module A — this is where you can use `{gargoyle}` for example:

- init https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/blob/master/golemR6/R/app_server.R#L12
- trigger https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/blob/master/golemR6/R/mod_a.R#L43
- watch https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/blob/master/golemR6/R/mod_b.R#L22

Please see https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/tree/master/golemR6 for a full working example.

PS : there is a missing ns() in your module :)

Colin

Comment: Thanks for all of these suggestions and the code example--that's very helpful. Is it possible to share the R6 object with the UI of module B so that I can print it to the user?

Comment: @itpetersen Sure, but the issue is that you have to update it from the server side — the UI is generated once at application launch, so if you want to update it you need to do something like `renderUI()` or `insertUI()` or `textOutput()` as in https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/blob/master/golemR6/R/mod_b.R#L14

Answer (score 3):

I made some correction to you code (some typo)

tl;dr : you cant acces questionnaire_responses in the UI.

`app_ui.R`:

```
same as you
```

`app_server.R`:

```
#' @import shiny
#' @import R6
#' @noRd
app_server <- function( input, output, session ) {
  
  # Generate R6 Class
  QuestionnaireResponses <- R6Class(
    classname = "QuestionnaireResponses",
    public = list(
      resp_id = NULL,
      timezone = NULL,
      timestamp = NULL,
      gender = NULL
    )
  )
  
  # Create new object to share data across modules using the R6 Class
  questionnaire_responses <- QuestionnaireResponses$new()
  
  # List the first level callModules here
  callModule(mod_a_server, "a_ui_1", questionnaire_responses)
  callModule(mod_b_server, "b_ui_1", questionnaire_responses)
}
```

`mod.R`:

```
mod_a_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    radioButtons(inputId = ns("gender"),
                 label = "What is your sex?",
                 choices = c("Male" = 1,
                             "Female" = 2),
                 selected = character(0))
  )
}

mod_a_server <- function(input, output, session, questionnaire_responses){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  # Add time start to the output vector
  timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
  timezone <- Sys.timezone()
  
  # Generate a survey-specific ID number
  resp_id <- paste0(sample(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), 10), collapse = "")
  
  # Assign values to R6 object
  questionnaire_responses$resp_id <- resp_id
  questionnaire_responses$timezone <- timezone
  questionnaire_responses$timestamp <- timestamp
  questionnaire_responses$gender <- "input$gender"
}


mod_b_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    print("questionnaire_responses$resp_id") # you can't access questionnaire_responses in the UI
  )
}

mod_b_server <- function(input, output, session, questionnaire_responses){
  ns <- session$ns
  print(questionnaire_responses$resp_id) # but here you can
}
```

Comment: and you can put your   QuestionnaireResponses <- R6Class(... inside an R script in the R folder.

Comment: That makes sense--thanks very much for the help. Is it possible to share the R6 object with the UI of module B so that I can print it to the user?